changing sun.security.smartcardio class
I am developing java project that communicates with smartcard. Project is based on JMRTD and SCUBA opensource libraries.
During development, I encountered issue when sending certain APDUs as secured messages. Debug process showed that sun.security.smartcardio.ChannelImpl class, process GetResponse APDU in a wrong way. In order to successfully communicate with smartcard, I need to change ChannelImpl class.
So, my project is using JMRTD and SCUBA libraries, which both refer to javax.smartcardio.
Furthermore, JavaSE-21 (which I am using) shows that java.smartcardio is used based on following module-info:
module java.smartcardio {
    exports javax.smartcardio;

    provides java.security.Provider with
        sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC;
}

To summarize, libraries used by my project are using javax.smartcardio, which in turn is implemented with classes from sun.security.smartcardio package.
It is clear that I cannot change (and don't want to change) JMRTD/SCUBA libraries.
My question: is there any way, that I can create my own implementation of ChannelImpl class, which will be recognized by JMRTD/SCUBA libraries, as well as by javax.smartcardio? (Have in mind, that ChannelImpl class is not directly called by any of my classes, or classes from JMRTD/SCUBA classes, but only from javax.smartcardio classes).
I tried to created my own implementation of ChannelImpl class, but I do not know if there is a way to instruct javax.smartcardio, to implement that class instead of sun.security.smartcardio.ChannelImpl class.

Milan, exactly how does ChannelImpl not process GET RESPONSE correctly?

Let me explain this issue:
If I try to read public key from my national ID card, GetData SM APDU need to be used. Content of public key is greater then 256 bytes, so when reading first "chunk" of data, SW 61xx is received. Unfortunatelly, sun class ChannelImpl is trying to send new APDU - GetResponse, in order to receive remaining bytes, but is not changing CLA byte. Therefore, second message that ChannelImpl is sending is formed like:
0C C0 00 00 xx (where xx points on remaining bytes).
My ID card recignizes that APDU as incorrect (SM without cryptogram and cryptocheck), so it returns SW 6987.
Within jmrtd/scuba, calling class (TerminalCardService) receives only first chunk, with second SW (6987), so it throws exception.
When using Windows smartcard middleware (based on C++), second (GetResponse) messages is sent as non-SM, ie: 00 C0 00 00 xx. Everything works fine then.
So, when anyone would try to use jmrtd/scuba for IAS/ECC SM communication, issue might happen if trying to use GetData SM APDUs that should receive chunks greater then 256 bytes (at least with national smartcards issued in my country).
